# xmllint is Killed while formatting huge file

Tags: linux, memory, xmllint

I'm trying to format a XML file (2.6G) using `xmllint` tool and redirecting the output to a file as:

```
xmllint --format response.xml > formatted.xml
```

When the process gets started it is taking all available memory. The output of:

```
free -m -c 10000 -s 30
```

Is given below:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290          92       15111           8          86       14974
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290          92       15111           8          86       14974
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       12706        1084           8        1498        2292
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15086         148           8          55          78
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15086         147           8          55          78
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15085         148           8          55          79
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15086         148           8          55          79
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15086         147           8          55          78
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15086         148           8          55          78
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15086         147           8          55          78
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15086         148           8          55          78
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15087         147           8          55          78
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15087         147           8          55          77
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15087         147           8          55          77
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15087         147           8          55          77
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15087         147           8          55          77
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15087         146           8          55          77
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15088         146           8          55          77
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15088         146           8          55          76
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15088         146           8          55          76
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15088         146           8          55          76
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15088         145           8          55          76
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15089         145           8          55          76
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15089         145           8          55          75
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15089         145           8          55          76
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15089         145           8          55          75
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15089         145           8          55          75
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15090         144           8          55          75
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15090         144           8          55          75
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15090         144           8          55          74
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15090         144           8          55          74
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15090         143           8          55          74
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15091         143           8          55          74
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15091         143           8          55          74
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15091         143           8          55          73
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15091         142           8          55          73
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15092         142           8          55          73
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15092         142           8          55          73
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15092         142           8          55          73
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15092         142           8          55          72
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15092         141           8          55          72
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15093         141           8          55          72
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15093         141           8          55          72
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15093         141           8          55          72
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15093         141           8          55          71
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15093         141           8          55          71
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15093         140           8          55          71
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15094         140           8          55          71
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15094         140           8          55          70
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15094         140           8          55          70
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15094         139           8          55          70
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15094         139           8          55          70
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15095         139           8          55          70
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15095         139           8          55          70
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15095         139           8          55          70
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15095         139           8          55          69
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15095         139           8          55          69
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15096         138           8          55          69
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15096         138           8          55          69
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15096         138           8          55          69
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15096         138           8          55          68
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15096         137           8          55          68
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15096         137           8          55          68
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15097         137           8          55          68
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15097         137           8          55          67
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15097         137           8          55          67
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15097         136           8          55          67
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15097         136           8          55          67
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15098         136           8          55          67
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15098         136           8          55          67
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15098         136           8          55          66
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15098         135           8          55          66
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15099         135           8          55          66
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15099         135           8          55          66
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15099         135           8          55          65
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15099         135           8          55          65
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15099         134           8          55          65
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15100         134           8          55          64
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290       15101         133           8          55          64
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290          94       15134           8          61       14983
Swap:             0           0           0

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15290          94       15133           8          61       14983
Swap:             0           0           0
```

After a while, the process is killed automatically after logging `Killed` in the console. How to process/format huge files using `xmllint`?

The OS version is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: While it's possible that the process got killed due to [rlimits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26860944/2303098 "How Limit memory usage for a single Linux process and not kill the process"), `xmllint` does have some [limitations in place](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758330#c1 "Bug 758330 - Memory allocation failed").

Comment: @ckujau, any known resolution?

Comment: Another option could be a SAX-based XML parser; `xmllint` I recall being DOM-based and thus hungry for memory.

Comment: @thrig, any command line tool, can you suggest, please?

Comment: I'd probably try `xml_pp` of the `XML::Twig` perl module.

Comment: I ended up using [xmlcutty](https://github.com/miku/xmlcutty) because `--xpath` did not work in combination with `--stream`.